# Are resolved dependencies destroyed in child task if main is returned

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, unity-container

I have constructor injection which resolves a repository dependency.

The repository is registered as follows:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<DbContext, ManagementContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository, GenericRepository>();
```

Code

***IssueService***

```
private readonly IGenericRepository _repository;

public IssueService(IGenericRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}

public IssueRequest CreateAndProcess(IssueRequest issueRequest)
{
    ...
    
    Task task = Task.Run(() => ProcessQIssueRequest(number));
    task.ConfigureAwait(false);

    return number;
}

private void ProcessQIssueRequest(int number)
{
    try
    {
       ...

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _repository.InsertOrUpdate(entity);
        _repository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

***WCF Service***

```
public class CrManagementService : ICrManagementService
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CrManagementService(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public string CreateAndProcessIssueRequest(IssueRequest contract)
    {
         try
         {
              IIssueService issueService = ContainerManager.Container.Resolve<IIssueService>();
              issueRequest = issueService.CreateAndProcess(contract);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
              ThrowHelper.ReThrow(ex, string.Format("{0}={1}", nameof(issueRequest.Entity.CrName), issueRequest.Entity.CrName));
         }
         return issueRequest.CrNumber;
    }
}
```

My question is: is the resolved `_repository` will be available in `ProcessQIssueRequest` till the end, or it be destroyed immediately after the `CreateAndProcessIssueRequest` method returns?

Comment: Careful with the tags! `unity3d` != `unity-container` ;)

Comment: You didn't post the complete proper code - but it **looks like** you have a class `IssueService` and `_repository ` is a local field on that class. As such, the value is initially set in the constructor, and remains available in that class - in **all** of it methods - for as long as the class instance exists. I don't know what you mean by *after the main method returns?* because such a class doesn't have a "main" method ....

Comment: @marc_s The IssueService is resolved in a WCF service and the next code is just the call response but the ProcessQIssueRequest will be working in the background. So request will end but the ProcessQIssueRequest will be still running. Will the _repository be available or will be destroyed?

Comment: As long as the class instance - the object of type `IssueService` - is still around, the `_repository` field on it will still be around

Comment: Actually for sure the WCF will respond to the request before the **ProcessQIssueRequest** ends. So will the object of type **IssueService** be destroyed or will waited until the task **ProcessQIssueRequest** ends.

Comment: You can view this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188454/angular-dependency-injection-services-lifetime

Comment: @TheobaldDu I don't know how this link supposed to be useful. The question is about resolved dependencies lifetime in backend not angular